# Rails caching: stale? always returns true in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Following [hawkins.io](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_2-using_strategies/) in my person model I have:

```
def self.cache_key
   Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{maximum(:updated_at)}.try(:to_i)-#{count}"
end
```

I am using Pundit for authorization. So in my people controller, I have:

```
def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    if authorize @person
      if stale? @person
        @person = Person.basic_details.last_details.find(params[:id]).decorate
        @person_histories = PersonHistory.new(person_id: @person.id).results
        respond_with @person
      end
    end
end
```

In my development.rb environment:

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join('tmp', 'cache'), { expires_in: 4.hours }
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

(I'm on Windows here so don't have memcached etc setup).

When I reload the person show view, immediately after loading it, I would expect it to be fully cached. Yet it requeries the database etc etc. Is there a setting or something I am missing? When I check the cache keys they are the same, but `stale? @person` always appears to return true.

Comment: it will have to do the person lookup from the db, so what exactly are the database queries that you think should be gone?

Comment: That was a case of tidying my code up for the purpose of an example too much! Here the second @person call links up a lot of models and would be around 200-400ms.  The second call is slightly less.  I really want to avoid these calls if nothing has been updated.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

Disable Rack::MiniProfiler caching

Rack::MiniProfiler middleware will remove headers related to caching and as such, stale? will ALWAYS RETURN TRUE. We can disable caching altogether using the following initializer:

```
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.disable_caching = false
```

Comment: I will try that and see if it works as I am using MiniProfiler.

Comment: Are you sending the etag and/ or last_modified value in If-None_Match and/ or If_Modified-Since headers in subsequent requests? If you won't, stale will always return true.

Comment: In the people controller I have  `etag { [current_user.try(:id), current_user.try(:locale)] }`

Comment: You need to the send the etag in the header in subsequent requests like this

[curl -I http://localhost:3000/books/1 --header 'If-None-Match: "ETAG"']

Comment: Thank you. This caused hours of frustration. Without that configuration in Rack::MiniProfiler, `if stale?` will ways return true.

Comment: Glad to help! Would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Comment: This is the correct answer - thanks, saved me a bunch of headaches....(once I found this answer!)

Comment: this works :). I read too many blogs to fix HTTP caching but didn't work